# How to print long strings in MAGMA?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

I'm trying to print a very long list to a file using magma to make it "callable". The list is called **F2**, and the code I'm using to print this list to a file is the following

```
SetOutputFile("...");
printf "F2 := %o ;", F2;
```

*(where, of course, ... is my file directory)* however, the list in the file is always **incomplete**, that is, the list is cut in some part.

I have not been able to determine the causes of this issue. I tried again with two lists, **F1** and **F2**, using the following code:

```
SetOutputFile("...");
printf "F1 := %o ; \n F2 := %o ;", F1, F2;
```

and, weirdly, **F1** is printed completely while **F2** is not.

I really appreciate any information you can give me. If I need to add some specifications about the system I'm using just let me know.

Comment: This is a wild guess as I've not used magma, but have you tried either adding a newline, or closing or otherwise flushing your output file? Perhaps there is a way to do that. Adding a newline might be enough if the output is lined buffered. Again, just some speculative ideas.

Comment: @James Thanks for your comment. I already tried adding a newline (it was the first thing I tried) and it worked, but using about 500 newlines!. I think Magma has issues printing long values, maybe there are some newlines that are not being considered or something like that.

Comment: The buffers won't be flushed until you execute 

UnsetOutputFile();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong mechanism for printing to a file in MAGMA. What you are doing is setting a file for the normal MAGMA buffer to output to; this means what would normally be printed to the screen is instead routed to a file. I'm guessing your intention is to write this MAGMA object to a file so you can read it in later in new MAGMA sessions.  In this case, you want to use the `PrintFile` command:

```
PrintFile(<filename>, "F1 := ");
PrintFile(<filename>, F1);
PrintFile(<filename>, ";\n F2 := ");
PrintFile(<filename>, F2);
PrintFile(<filename>, ";");
```

It can be a bit tricky to get MAGMA to read back in these objects from the file in an efficient way; what I tend to do is to save a single object to a file, using `PrintFileMagma`, which makes sure this is written to the file in the proper MAGMA format:

```
PrintFileMagma("F1.mgo", F1);
```

Then I have a custom function defined in my startup file to read these back in:

```
FOB := function(N)
    s := Read(N);
    OB := eval s;
    return OB;
end function;
```

Then in a new MAGMA session I can simply type

```
F1 := FOB("F1.mgo");
```

to import the desired object.

**Edit:** It was mentioned that MAGMA doesn't write some objects like `AssociativeArray` properly in Magma mode.

One workaround for this particular case is to save the AssociativeArray as a list of tuples,

```
PrintMagmaMode("filename.mgo", [* <k,A[k]> : k in Keys(A) *]);
```

and then convert back into an associative array when you load using.. well it seems a for loop is the only way to initialize an associative array.

```
A := AssociativeArray();
for a in FOB("filename.mgo") do
   A[a[1]] := a[2];
end for;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works well. I might extend this function to deal with more complex data structures (e.g. tuples whose components are AssociativeArrays, of which I have a few).